# How it is possible 5 different colors of each row in listview if items are more then ten in listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Make an array as given below as no of list item i suppose u have five items:

```
int[] color_arr={Color.BLUE,Color.CYAN,Color.YELLOW,Color.GREEN,Color.RED};
```

and using it in `getView()` method of custom adapter as below:-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {

     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     View row=convertView;

     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custome, parent, false);
     row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);// this set background color

     TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
     ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_list);

     textview.setText(data_text[position]);
     imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

     return (row);

    }
```

**My Question is if more then 5 items in list item how it possible 5 different colors of each row in listview ?**

Comment: Yes it should be possible. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: set variable in globle int count = 0;
Change this line 
row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[count]);// this set background color

if(count >= 5){
 count = 0;
}

count++;

Comment: This code is running fine if 5 items are available in listView, if more then 5 items are available in then how it set 5 background colors in listView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position % color_arr.length]);
```

Answer (score 6):

you are having 5 values in array, so if list is having more than 5 items definitely it will crash because it can not find `data_image[5]`

You can use `%` operator

```
imageview.setBackgroundColor(data_image[position % 5]);
```

For 0-4th position it will work as its working now, for 5th position it will set color of position 0, for 6th position it will set color of position 1 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position % color_arr.length]);
```