# How to set ImageView Looping while i only have limited images ? (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, loops, imageview

I have array drawable, the array drawable only have 4 images, and i have could be more than 4 ImageView, How to set image on the ImageView by looping, and when the looping reach more than 4, i want it's return to the first image, so it will be like this:

- ImageView 1 with first drawable
- ImageView 2 with second drawable
- ImageView 3 with third drawable
- ImageView 4 with fourth drawable
- ImageView 5 with first drawable
- ImageView 6 with second drawable

and so on..

How to do that ?
Any help will be appreciate, thank you!

Comment: check for image array position and reset it at 4.. in your loop

Comment: hint: use `%` and `/` with `Array`s

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855695/how-it-is-possible-5-different-colors-of-each-row-in-listview-if-items-are-more/) might give you some hint

Comment: so, it's "images [ i % images.length]" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can use % operator. It returns remainder of a division.
For example, if you have 6 views and 4 images, you can do this way:

```
ImageView[] viewsArray = new ImageView[6];
//init your array with findViewById()

for(int i = 0; i < viewsArray.length; ++i) {
   viewsArray[i].setImageDrawable(imagesArray[i % 4]); // if your index is 5 % operator will return 1.  
}
```